# p:dataList not updating

Tags: java, primefaces, ejb

I have `p:datalist` which contains Set of objects and `p:commandButton` that should add one object to this set. But whatever I do, the `datalist` is updated too soon, and does not contain new object. But when I click for example 2 times, `datalist` is refreshed 2 times and after first refresh it does not contain any new element, but after 2nd first element is added. How can I synchronize this update? I tried `update="id"/"@all"`, sync/async, ajax, but it is always the same.

Page

```
        <m:form id="lastForm">
            <p:commandButton id="addProject" action="#{userBacking.addProject}" value="myadd">
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:dataList id="mydatalist" value="#{userBacking.user.projects.toArray()}" var="project">
                #{project.projectName}, #{project.id}
            </p:dataList>
        </m:form>
```

UserBacking class

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class UserBacking {
   private User user;

   @Inject
   private UserService userService;
   (...)
   public void addProject() {
      userService.addProject(user);
   }
}
```

UserService

```
@Stateless
public class UserService extends BaseEntityService<Long, User> {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    (...)
    public void addProject(User user) {
        User existingUser = get(user);
        Project proj = new Project();
        proj.setProjectName("projectname");
        proj.setUser(existingUser);
        existingUser.addProjects(proj);
        super.update(existingUser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `update="mydatalist"` attribute to your `<p:commandButton ... />`. Also use `@ViewScoped` instead of `@RequestScoped` in your backing bean. A RequestScoped bean is created at every request therefore loses the data previously stored. The ViewScoped bean instead is cleared and recreated only when the root element changes i.e. `UIViewRoot`. `@ViewScoped` backing bean should be sufficient to manage a page that works with ajax.

Comment: It was all about @ViewScoped.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you need to `actionListener` instead of `action` in your command button (besides the update attribute that is missing in your example, though you say you are using it). `action` has its place during normal  POST synchronous requests to the server.

Additionally the general practice in my projects is that when an ajax processing was used in a certain page, we have used `@ViewScoped` beans instead of `RequestScoped` ones.

Comment: It was all about ViewScoped, but @eni-sinanaj was 4 minutes faster.